# Vlan State from MIB-2

Tags: networking, port, snmp, cisco, mib

I need to get [vtpVlanState](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=vtpVlanState) results on MIB-2.
I need the vlan indexes that this object returns and I need to know whether this vlan is active.

The reason I want to do this in mib-2 is because I want to do the same command(snmp) in all the switches and not only on cisco.

Is there anyway to do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get VTP information from MIB-II.  VTP is a Cisco proprietary protocol and MIB-II (specified by IETF in [RFC 1213](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1213)) does not support proprietary protocols

**EDIT after comments**

If you're looking for IETF MIBs to poll for device Vlan definitions, look at `dot1qVlanStatus` from [Q-BRIDGE-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4363)

Comment: Hi,
What I am doing is this:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094a9b.shtml

But instead of using vtpVlanState to get the vlans I want to use MIB-II in some way to get the vlans.
I found [dot1qVlan](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4) which is on MIB-II.
But for some reason I don't get results with it on my switches

Comment: @Lior, First, they are not querying MIB-II in that link.  They are polling [RFC 1493 Bridge MIB](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1493).  Be sure you follow the examples on the page closely.  Note that communities are in the form of `public@<vlan_number>`, so polling for Vlan 12 requires `snmpwalk c public@12 hostname oid`

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But in order to get the vlan number they are using a private mib(CISCO-VTP-MIB). I need to find a way to get the same result(vlan number) on a Dell or Juniper Switch.

Comment: Then use `dot1qVlanStatus` from [Q-BRIDGE-MIB](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4363); the raw OIDs are [here](http://www.mibsearch.com/objview/Q-BRIDGE-MIB)